# React Native native-stack gestureEnabled: false not working for iOS app

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack

I have an iOS application where the login and start pages are handled by one Stack Navigator:

```
const AppNavigator = () => {
<NavigationContainer>
    <Navigator screenOptions = {{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}} initialRouteName="">
        <Screen name ="Start" component = {Start}></Screen>
        <Screen name ="Login" component = {Login} ></Screen>
    </Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

}

Once you log in via the Login screen, you are redirected to screens handled by another Stack Navigator:

```
const InventoryNav = () => {
  return (
   <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
     headerShown: false, // Hide the header.
     gestureEnabled: false,
    }}
    initialRouteName="Main"
   >
  <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainInventory}/>
  <Stack.Screen name="Create Category" component={CreateCategory} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Category List" component={CategoryItemsList} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Create Product" component={CreateProduct} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Edit Product" component={EditProduct} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

);
};

However, once I'm on an inventory page, if I swipe right it takes me back to the login page and essentially logs me out. I've tried applying the `gestureEnabled` prop at the Stack Navigator level in `screenOptions`, as well as at the Stack Screen level in `option`, but neither seems to work. How can I disable back swipe?

I am using

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12"
```